# Why does rails not generate specs but minitests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using rails 7.
I've just installed `rspec-rails` in this way:

```rb
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end
```

And I generated a controller.

```
$ rails g controller welcome home
      create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome/home'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/welcome
      create    app/views/welcome/home.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
```

But I found out that rails generated minitests instead of specs.

Why is this? What should I do to fix this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to add `rspec-rails` to `:development` group in order to get generators working.

```rb
# Gemfile
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end
```

I found this out [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#installation)